# What does this graph mean?

Tags: statistics

I know little about economics and am very confused on what this graph represents. 
 I found it when I saw that the President had tweeted it and was wondering what it mean.  Specifics what "Jobs plentiful" and "jobs hard to get" are measured in.[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Economics.SE! Could you provide a link to the question that you had in mind? Also, it might help to provide a title that is more relevant to the content of the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data plotted in the graph are based on a consumer survey conducted by *Conference Board*. They ask consumers how hard it to get a job. If 34.1% of people say that "jobs are plentiful" and 18% of people say "jobs are hard to get" then the figure would plot a value of $34.1-18=16.1$.

The figure originally comes from [this Bloomberg article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-07-25/u-s-consumer-confidence-unexpectedly-rises-to-four-month-high), but you can read a little more about the underlying data [here](https://www.conference-board.org/data/consumerconfidence.cfm).

Comment: I find it perplexing that this question is on-topic.